# redirect to a page with php and and also submit POST data

Tags: php, redirect, url-routing

I want to **redirect** to a page after executing a php function and also submit a html form with the methode `POST`, at once.

I found many solutions with `GET` but I **want** to handle this with `POST`.

Comment: redirect and post at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cUrl` to send POST data you want, then make the redirect.

Look on the net for: "php curl".

Answer (score 0):

Make your `form action` point to the php document where you want to execute your function and then in the end place this `header("location: your_location_file.php");`

Step one - submit form to functions.php
Step two - do what ever you need to do with the submited data
Step three - Redirect

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="functions.php">
...
</form>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
...
all your code
...
header("location: your_location_file.php");
?>
```

Comment: That's nice, but he wants to transfer the post data to your_location_file.php.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can help if you don't want to rely on curl. Had this laying around.  Pass in $_POST or an array of the data you want posted. Add error/parameter checking.

```
function http_post_redirect($url='', $data=array(), $doc=true) {

    $data = json_encode($data);

    if($doc) { echo "<html><head></head><body>"; }

    echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var data = eval('(' + '$data' + ')');
        var jsForm = document.createElement('form');

        jsForm.method = 'post';
        jsForm.action = '$url';

        for (var name in data) {
            var jsInput = document.createElement('input');
            jsInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            jsInput.setAttribute('name', name);
            jsInput.setAttribute('value', data[name]);
            jsForm.appendChild(jsInput);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(jsForm);
        jsForm.submit();
    </script>";

    if($doc) { echo "</body></html>"; }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. how must the array `$data` look like? with this: `$data = array (
"year" => "2013",
"month" => "3"
);` it is not working. its redirecting but the POST data is not submited

Comment: Must have copied an old one, sorry.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a session to hold the POST data.

I am currently using code like below. On my first page load, the $_POST data is checked. If it contains certain values already in the database, then it redirects to a page for those values.

```
// This could be part of the same script as below, or a different script.
session_start();

if($_POST['my_value'] && valueExistsInMyDb($_POST['my_value']) ) { // check my db to see if this is an existing value

  $id = getIdOfMyValue($_POST['my_value']); // e.g. '4'

  $_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST; // take ALL post data and save it in the session variable

  header("location: your.php?myvalue=" . $id); // redirect to bookmarkable target page where $_GET variable matches what was posted.
  exit();  // ensure no other code is executed in this script after header is issued.
}
```

Then your other file (or maybe even the same file) could do this:

```
// your.php?myvalue=4

if(isset($_SESSION) && array_key_exists('POST',$_SESSION)) {
  $_POST = $_SESSION['POST']; // creates or overwrites your $_POST array with data from the session. The rest of your script won't be able to tell that it's not a real $_POST, which may or may not be what you want.
  unset($_SESSION['POST']); // you probably want to remove the data from the session.
}
// now your myvalue=4 is stored in GET, and you can handle the rest of the POST data as you like
```

I don't know if that is the best solution, but so far it seems to be working for me so far. I only just wrote the code a few days ago and haven't tested all aspects yet.

Another option is to use HTML5 to change the address bar. No redirect needed. But the downside is that only "modern Webkit browsers" can use it, apparently.